# can we limit the number of documents return in flwor expression?

Tags: xquery, marklogic, flwor

I have many documents in a database where I want to search for a specific condition. I saw can use predicates, but it works under only one document, is that correct?

FLOWR expression work with many documents under whole database, but while returning the number the document can we use predicate `[]` too for limiting the number of rows to return.

Need to get all points while querying a document and query across a Database or whole database in Marklogic 10.

Comment: You can apply criteria in a predicate `[]` filter or in the `where` clause of a FLWOR. Example code and a more detailed description of the filter conditions would be helpful, and we could provide some concrete examples.

Comment: Thanks , so you mean [] inside a FLWOR expression works fine , i just want to to get 20 docs to return now, so [20] i can put in where clause of FLWOR expression.

Comment: predicates work on the set and within the FLWOR. If you want the first 20 docs, you could apply a predicate to the search `cts:search(doc(), cts:true-query())[1 to 20]` or you could filter the results of the FLWOR: `(for $doc in cts:search(doc(), cts:true-query())[1 to 100] return $doc)[1 to 20]`, or apply a `where` clause limiting with some criteria within the FLWOR, or a combination. Describe what you are trying to do and we can more easily answer how to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
for $x at $position in ....
where $position le 100
return ...
```